# How can I encrypt my router admin page login session?

Tags: passwords

I login to my router using the web connection but the session is not encrypted, is there a third party way to encrypt the web session so no one on my network can sniff the password?

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell us what type of router do you have? Also this question is better suited to [super user](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: It is a NETGEAR WNDR3700

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:**

Configure your router configuration tool to use HTTPS. If you can't do that, read on.

(If you're not sure *how* to do that, I'd suggest asking on [Super User](http://superuser.com) with the make and model of your router. However, I can't guarantee it will be on-topic, so read SU's [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and decide for yourself.)

**Long answer:**

Generally the only way to encrypt a connection with an host that only supports insecure connections is to establish a secure connection with an intermediary server, which then performs the unencrypted connection to the target host.

**[Client]** ===(*encrypted*)===> **[VPN / SSH Server]** ===(*not encrypted*)===> **[Host]**

As you can see, this only pushes the insecure connection to some other part of the network. VPNs are best when they're used to connect to hosts that are network-topologically adjacent to the VPN server -- e.g., connecting *from* anywhere the wild, wild Net, *into* a corporate network: the VPN server and the desired corporate host are in the same server room. The second, unencrypted connection hop happens across trusted network hardware. (See also Server Fault's [Does VPN secure web traffic?](https://serverfault.com/a/231726))

Your case, however, is very different. You are already *right next to* the server you want to access (i.e., the router's HTTP server), and you don't trust the security of that *one hop*, because you're afraid others on the network can see it. You can mildly increase security by using a wired connection over a wireless connection: an active attacker must use ARP poisoning to get your packets, while a passive attacker can no longer read them out of the air. This does not actually solve your problem, of course.

You could make an encrypted connection *out* of your local network, to a remotely hosted tunnel server (e.g., VPN/SSH), and then make an unencrypted hop back *into* your router from the Internet. (As an additional practical step, this requires you to enable port forwarding from TCP 80 to your router's local IP.) In that case, you don't expose your credentials to attackers on your local network, but you do send your credentials in the clear across the network path between the remote VPN and your home.

I suppose it comes down to which you trust more: the devices attached to your local network, or some unknown Internet routers that run between your home and the remote VPN.